# Might GQL IN operator be used to search entities which have an item in a list Property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, datastore

I mean, if you have a model, just like this (Python)

```
class MahModel(db.Model):
```

which has a tags property(for instance)

```
    tags = db.StringListProperty()
```

Can I do something like this in a query?  `WHERE 'x' IN tags`

If not, what kind of workaround could I use?

My actual code is like follows:
Ad.gql("WHERE paid = True AND delivered = False AND '" + cat + "' IN boards ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1").get()

boards is a list, in which I wanna get a match with the cat variable

That gives me this error:
`ad_ = Ad.gql("WHERE paid = True AND delivered = False AND '" + cat + "' IN boards ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1").get()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1208, in gql

    *args, **kwds)

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__

    self._proto_query = gql.GQL(query_string, _app=app, namespace=namespace)

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 195, in __init__

    if not self.__Select():

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 813, in __Select

    return self.__From()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 834, in __From

    return self.__Where()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 846, in __Where

    return self.__FilterList()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 871, in __FilterList

    return self.__FilterList()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 871, in __FilterList

    return self.__FilterList()

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 853, in __FilterList

    self.__Error('Invalid WHERE Identifier')

  File "C:\Programme\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 738, in __Error

    (error_message, self.__symbols[self.__next_symbol]))

BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol 'tf2'`

Comment: what happens when you tried it?

Comment: Gives me a weird error... lemme bump it: BadQueryError: Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol 'x'

Comment: Please add new information about your problem by editing your question.

Comment: Please, please don't substitute user data into a GQL expression. We provide parameterized queries (use ':1' in the expression and pass it as an argument) for exactly that. As to the error - 'tf2' doesn't appear anywhere in the expression. You need to include the original, unmodified query and stacktrace if we're to be of any help debugging.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE tags = 'x'
```

will return any entities that have 'x' at least once in the list.